# Taylor series for a non-elementar integral form

Tags: real-analysis

I'm asked to write the first two terms of the Taylor series (so, degree 0 and degree 1) of this integral form

$$\int_{2x^2}^{x^2+x}\sin(t^2)dt$$

which integral isn't expressed by any combination of elementary function. 
The point is, am I forced to somehow calculate that integral to achieve the task? If yes, the only method I could come up with is substitution, that is putting
$$t^2 = x $$ 
obtaining thus 
$$\int_{2t^4}^{t^4+t^2} x\sqrt{x}  \sin(x) dt$$
which looks hard to integrate. Is there a smart and faster way to do this?

Comment: Where is the Taylor series centered around? To answer your last question, the answer is yes, use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin(t^2)$ is an entire function, hence it can be regarded as a "polynomial with infinite degree", if we carefully list the involved monomials according to the ascending order of their degrees:
$$ \sin(t^2) = t^2-\frac{t^6}{3!}+\frac{t^{10}}{5!}-\ldots $$
and we may perform $\int_{2x^2}^{x^2+x}(\ldots)\,dt$ termwise:
$$ \int_{2x^2}^{x^2+x}\sin(t^2)\,dt = \left[\frac{t^3}{3}\right]_{2x^2}^{x^2+x}-\left[\frac{t^7}{7\cdot 3!}\right]_{2x^2}^{x^2+x}+\ldots $$
in order to recognize that the RHS is $x^3$ multiplied by an entire function of the $x$ variable.
 It follows that in a neighbourhood of the origin
$$ \int_{2x^2}^{x^2+x}\sin(t^2)\,dt = \frac{x^3}{3}+x^5+O(x^6).$$

Answer (score 0):

$p(x) = f(0) + f'(0) x + \frac 12 f''(0)x^2 + \frac 1{3!} f'''(0)x^3\cdots\\
f(0) = \int_0^0 \sin(t^2) dt = 0\\
f'(x) = \sin ((x^2 + x)^2)(2x+1) - \sin((2x^2)^2) (4x)\\
f'(0) = 0\\
f''(x) = \cos ((x^2 + x)^2)(2)(x^2 + x)(2x+1)^2 - \cos((2x^2)^2)(64x^4) + 2\sin ((x^2 + x)^2)(2) - 4\sin((2x^2)^2) \\
f''(0) = 0$

etc.